# Inserting Record From XML file to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, xml

I want to store data from a xml file to mysql.

My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?><data>
<ApplicantName>Test</ApplicantName>
<ExamName>Exam</ExamName>
<ContactNoPresent>9999999999</ContactNoPresent>
<Language>English</Language>
</data>
```

I tried the following:

```
load XML local infile 'D:\\a.xml' into table asdb.abc rows identified by '<ApplicantName>';
```

It works and inserts the Applicant name to the table. But I am not able to find how to store all the values from the xml to mysql table. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know dirty hacks to do it, however a cleaner approach would be to use JAX-RS to parse xml requests and persist it into an Object oriented database like hibernate comes for free.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your rows (in fact, the one an only row I can see in your XML stream) are actually identified by the `<data>` tag.